# Jquery datatable show hide

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatable

I used the datatable script for my table. Here i have displayed the list of products.

Below is the html code for table (For this table i applied datatable script also)

```
            <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="example" class="hovertable menuclass display">
        <thead>
        <th width="13%" style="padding-left:3px;">Actions</th>
        <th width="21%">Name</th>
        <th width="12%">col2</th>
        <th width="18%">col3</th>
        <th width="10%">col4</th>
        <th width="7%">col5</th>
        <th width="10%">col6</th>
        <th width="5%" class="last">col7</th>
        </thead>

        <tr  >
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="width:95px;"><img src="images/minus_icon.png" alt="" border="0">  </td>

        <td align="left" valign="top">name1</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">val</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
        value</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">tetse</td>
        <td align="center" valign="top">test</td>
        <td align="right" valign="top">test</td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" class="last">241</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr  >
        <td align="left" valign="top" style="width:95px;"><img src="images/minus_icon.png" alt="" border="0">  </td>

        <td align="left" valign="top">name2</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">val</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">
        value</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">tetse</td>
        <td align="center" valign="top">test</td>
        <td align="right" valign="top">test</td>
        <td align="center" valign="top" class="last">241</td>
        </tr>         

        </table>
```

My table row appearance is like this

[image]

When i click the '-' image then the row will be hidden and display as

[image]

If i click the undo link then again the corresponding row should be displayed.

I used the following code to hide the particular row.

```
$('.hdrow').live('click', function(){
   $(this).closest('tr').toggle();
});
```

**Please refer the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/2F2E5/2/**

I dont know how to implement this. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Refer Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/2F2E5/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on click of minus hide the closest row and keep one td to show hidden messages.

```
// Live is depreciated use new `on` method.
$(document).on('click','.minusSign',function(){
    $(this).closest('tr').children().hide();
    $(this).closest('tr').find('td.message').show();
    // Assuming td.message is another table data with 'Product name is now hidden `undo`'
});
```

and on click of undo hide message `td` and show the row.

```
$(document).on('click','td.message a.undu',function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('tr').children().show();
    $(this).closest('td.message').hide(); // Here `this` is undo link
});
```

this should be quick and enough.